# How to resolve UDP packets being dropped given netstat reporting SndbufErrors

Tags: centos6, udp, openstack, netstat

I have a server instance on an `OpenStack` that at a pretty high load starts loosing `UDP` packets. I captured all outgoing packets using `tcpdump` and some of them are missing, even though application logs imply that they should have been sent. Usual packet size is around 60-120 bytes.

Running `netstat -s` gives:

```
[root@myServer] ~> netstat -s | grep Udp: -A 5
Udp:
    3855490640 packets received
    133199 packets to unknown port received.
    89 packet receive errors
    4116940753 packets sent
    SndbufErrors: 1396176
```

When the server is under load, `SndbufErrors` keeps increasing. I tried to figure out what might be causing it but with no luck even though it feels like this should be covered somewhere.

**Q: What might be the reasons for this and how could I resolve this?**

Investigation I've done:

1. Running `ifconfig -a` doesn't show any errors:

   ```
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
     RX packets:6361554048 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:6902945025 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
   ```

   I tried increasing `txqueuelen` to `10'000` (by running `ifconfig eth1 txqueuelen 10000`), but it didn't make a difference.
2. Running several `sysctl` commands I get:

   ```
   net.core.rmem_max = 124928
   net.core.wmem_max = 4194304
   net.core.rmem_default = 124928
   net.core.wmem_default = 124928
   ```

   I tried increasing `net.core.rmem_max` and `net.core.wmem_max` to much bigger number `16'777'216`, but still keep getting the same errors.
3. Running `sar -n UDP 1 1` gives (approximated values, but no errors):

   ```
   05:47:31 PM    idgm/s    odgm/s  noport/s idgmerr/s
   05:48:46 PM  23000.00  24000.00      0.00      0.00
   ```
4. Running `ethtool` on the `Openstack` VM instance mostly results in `Operation not supported`. Running `ethtool` on the `Openstack` host server choosing its interface that is used to communicate with outside world, I get:

   ```
   [root@myServer] ~> ethtool em1
       Speed: 1000Mb/s
       ... 

   [root@myServer] ~> ethtool -g em1
       Ring parameters for em1:
       Pre-set maximums:
       RX:             4096
       RX Mini:        0
       RX Jumbo:       0
       TX:             4096
       Current hardware settings:
       RX:             256
       RX Mini:        0
       RX Jumbo:       0
       TX:             256
   ```

   I am not convinced that it can be related though as errors I see are inside the VM and not the `Openstack` host server. Update: I increased the `RX` and `TX` values, but to no success.

Comment: What are your udp buffer memory settings and what are the average size packets you are sending?  Also, what is the speed of the nic and what is your peak throughput?

Comment: @Aaron I updated question with an average packet size. How do I find out buffer memory settings? I looked at `/etc/systl.conf` but it doesn't have anything useful. And also, how do I find speed of nic?

Comment: Usually `ethtool DEVICENAME` or `mii-tool` unless this is one of your VM's in openstack, then you would need to run those commands on the compute bare metal node.  The sysctl settings above are not default so you might ask whomever tuned them to assist in your troubleshooting.

Comment: I noticed you updated the question to include the packet size, ty.  60-120 bytes is very small.  Do you know what application is creating them and how many packets per second you are sending?  If you install `iftop` you can see the throughput.  `sar` can give you some idea of packet rate.  `sar` may even give more details about packets being drops in percentages.

Comment: @Aaron I know the application that is sending the requests, but it is not helping me in diagnosing why they are missing.

Comment: @eddyP Does the application do transmit pacing? If not, you should expect to lose lots of datagrams.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what do you mean by transmit pacing? And why should I expect to lose lots of datagrams? `RcvbufErrors` isn't reporting any errors.

Comment: @eddyP Transmit pacing means that you carefully control the timing of datagram sending to avoid datagram loss. If you don't do this, you should expect to lose lots of datagrams because that's how datagrams work. Errors won't necessarily be reported because the loss can occur at various different points in the path and each error counter only tracks some single point. You likely need to set a burst level and a data rate and delay sending UDP datagrams that exceed the allowed data rate and burst level. Otherwise, a "clump" of datagrams will result in loss somewhere.